# Search query for keyword search in a particular list Sharepoint Hosted app/add in Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, search-api, keyword, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to add keyword search functionality using REST api on a **particular list**. I have got the result using the query as :

`var queryUrl = appWeb + "/_api/search/query?querytext='" + keyWord + "+AND+ListId:" + listId + "'";`

Where listId is list GUID.
The problem with the result is that its a very weird object that I am getting and I am not even sure if I am getting correct results.

The ask here is that I need all the rows which has this particular keyword and hence would require a JSON object (for jquery bootgrid grid population) with all the column data in it.

Currently the object does not have that.

[Reference](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4e3ce7/sharepoint-2013-search-in-app-web-using-rest-api/)

> Please note that if there is another approach, maybe JSOM, could you
>   please share how to achieve this?

Comment: Since you are running this in the SharePoint hosted addin, check whether the addin has permissions in the list which you are trying to search. Search results are security trimmed, you might not find results if you don't have access.

Comment: Yes i have given permission also '<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/search" Right="QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal" /> '